# Can I have a "Forgot your password?" mechanism when using 2-factor authentication?

Tags: password-recovery, two-factor-authentication

After some research I have implemented a solid "Forgot your password?" mechanism, and now I wanted to implement 2FA.

But now I'm thinking, what's the point of 2FA (password + email or SMS), if you can recover your account with the "Forgot your password?" mechanism, which only requires 1 factor (only email)?

Is it normal to have both or, as I'm now thinking, it's kind of pointless?

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the 2-factor authentication is, that people often use the one email addresse for all their accounts and additionally choose a weak password which they use for all their accounts.

So if someone else get access to that password on one system, this person will have access to all other accounts.
If the user has choosen a password for his email that is different to all others the situation is a little bit better. But there is still one problem that remains. If someone was able to guess that password the user would not recognize this until it is to late.

But if the mobile is lost or stolen the probability is height, that the user will request a *blocking* of the SIM card within a short period of time.

So you would send a confirmation code for actions of the account of the user that are uncommon or could result in loosing access to the account.

It is up to you to choose when you send a verification code. (Always on login, only on changes of account data e.g. Password, email, new mobile number or for actions that would create costs for the user)